# Telerik Mvc Grid and AntiForgeryToken

Tags: telerik, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to set things up with my grid such that every action that every ajax post will include an antiforgery token.  My gird is set up like so:

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
     .Name("Folks")
     .Sortable(x => x.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
     .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
     .Footer(true)
     .Pageable(x => x.PageSize(25).Total((int)ViewData["total"]))
     .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax())
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
        columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(120).Title("First Name");
        columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(120).Title("Last Name");
     })
     .Selectable()
     .ClientEvents(events =>
     {
         events.OnDataBinding("Test");
     })
)
```

The handler for OnDataBinding (Test) looks like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Test(e) {
          var valTokenValue = $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();
          e.data = { __RequestVerificationToken: valTokenValue };
      }
    </script>
```

I thought the argument (e) had a property called data which accepted a dictionary of values.  However, FireBug keeps complaining saying that "data is undefined".  Any ideas how I can include the token with every request? I'm using version 2011.Q2.712. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can't attach your token if there is no object to attach to.  Create a Json object and set it to data if data is null/length=0/undefined (I know, overkill on the checking).  I did the checking in a separate function so I wouldn't have to repeat the check every time I made an ajax call.

```
(function (TelerikGrid, $, undefined) {
TelerikGrid.OnDataBinding = function (e) {
    e.data = AntiForgery.AddToken(e.data);
};})(window.TelerikGrid = window.TelerikGrid || {}, jQuery);


(function (AntiForgery, undefined) {
AntiForgery.AddToken = function (data) {
    data = ((data == null || data.length == 0 || data == undefined) ? { } : data);
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
};
})(window.AntiForgery = window.AntiForgery || {});
```